# Perform operation on all "key":"value" pair in dict and store the result in a new dict object

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary `S` as:

```
{1: [11.1, 13, 15.0], 2: [6.9, 8.5, 10.17], 3: [3.86, 4.83, 6.07], 4: [3.86, 4.83, 6.07], 5: [2.31, 2.58, 3.02]}
```

And an array `D1_inv` as:

```
[0.0248, 0.0296, 0.0357]
```

I need to obtain a product of all the items in S and D1_inv. For example, for `S[1]`:

```
[round(i*j,4) for i,j in zip(S[1],D1_inv)]
Out[282]: [0.2753, 0.3848, 0.5355]
```

and for `S[2]`:

```
[round(i*j,4) for i,j in zip(S[2],D1_inv)]
Out[283]: [0.1711, 0.2516, 0.3631]
```

Can somebody help me create a loop so that I can store all these products in a dict like S?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use *dictionary comprehension* to achieve this. Within your dictionary comprehension, you need to call your *list comprehension* to round off the product of numbers for each list present as value in the original `my_dict` dictionary. It can be achieved as:

```
my_dict = {1: [11.1, 13, 15.0], 2: [6.9, 8.5, 10.17], 3: [3.86, 4.83, 6.07], 4: [3.86, 4.83, 6.07], 5: [2.31, 2.58, 3.02]}
d1_inv = [0.0248, 0.0296, 0.0357]

new_dict = {k: [round(i*j,4) for i, j in zip(v,d1_inv)] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

where `new_dict` will be a dictionary holding each `key` in your initial `my_dict` with the corresponding value as:

```
{1: [0.2753, 0.3848, 0.5355], 2: [0.1711, 0.2516, 0.3631], 3: [0.0957, 0.143, 0.2167], 4: [0.0957, 0.143, 0.2167], 5: [0.0573, 0.0764, 0.1078]}
```

---

**Explanation:** This solution comprised of:

- an outer dictionary comprehension expression, and
- an inner list comprehension expression.

Here, the outer *dictionary comprehension*:

```
{k: [...*list comprehension*...] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

will iterate over the dictionary pulling the tuple of `("key", "value")` pairs returned by `my_dict.items()`. Here I am using `k` as a key to the new dictionary, where as value `v` will be used in the inner *list comprehension* expression:

```
[round(i*j,4) for i, j in zip(v,d1_inv)]
```

Here, `zip(v,d1_inv)` will return the tuple of objects corresponding to same position in `d1_inv` and `v` *(from outer dictionary comprehension)* , and then we are calling `round()` function on product of the elements present in tuple `(i, j)` returned by `zip()`'s iteration.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this one:

```
result = dict((k, [round(i*j,4) for i,j in zip(S[k],D1_inv)]) for k in S.keys())
```

Answer (score 2):

This comprehension should do it:

```
{k: [round(i*j, 4) for i, j in zip(v, D1_inv)] for k, v in S.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  ! :)